# Left join Subquery with typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have the following table

Article, User, and Comment . One user can have multiple comments and articles, I am trying to write a query that select List of `Comments` along with the `User` info and total `Article` written by the `User`. The query below

```
this.commentRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('comment')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.commentRatings', 'commentRatings')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.user', 'user')
        .where('comment.articleId = :id', { id })
        .select([
          'comment.id',
          'comment.comment',
          'user.name',
          'user.profilePhoto',
          'user.createdOn',
          'commentRatings',
          'comment.createdOn',
        ])
        .orderBy({ 'comment.createdOn': { order: order, nulls: 'NULLS LAST' } })
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .getMany()
```

Returns exactly what I need in terms for `User` Info, The `Comment` and the `Rating`, the `articlesCount` of each user is what I am not able to get. I tried adding a `subQuery` as a `leftJoinAndSelect` like

```
const userPostsQuery = this.commentRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .subQuery()
      .from(User, 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.posts', 'article')
      .select('SUM(user.id)', 'sum')
      .getQuery();
```

And

```
this.commentRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('comment')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.commentRatings', 'commentRatings')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.user', 'user')
        .loadRelationCountAndMap('comment.article', 'article')
        .leftJoinAndSelect(userPostsQuery, 'userPostsQuery')
        .where('comment.articleId = :id', { id })
        .select([
          'comment.id',
          'comment.comment',
          'user.name',
          'user.profilePhoto',
          'user.createdOn',
          'commentRatings',
          'comment.createdOn',
        ])
        .orderBy({ 'comment.createdOn': { order: order, nulls: 'NULLS LAST' } })
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .getMany()
```

The above query throws an error > error: syntax error at or near `"WHERE"`

I then tried

```
this.commentRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('comment')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.commentRatings', 'commentRatings')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.user', 'user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
          (qb) =>
            qb
              .from(Article, 'article')
              .leftJoinAndSelect('article.user', 'user')
              .loadRelationCountAndMap('article.user', 'article.user'),
          'userQuery',
        )
        .where('comment.articleId = :id', { id })
        .select([
          'comment.id',
          'comment.comment',
          'user.name',
          'user.profilePhoto',
          'user.createdOn',
          'commentRatings',
          'comment.createdOn',
        ])
        .orderBy({ 'comment.createdOn': { order: order, nulls: 'NULLS LAST' } })
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .getMany()
```

Throws an error

> error: syntax error at or near `"WHERE"`

Pls how do I append the `totalArticle` by user in each `Comment` row? Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `loadRelationCountAndMap` method to load the total count of articles for each user.

For more example  [usage](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/query-builder/relation-count/relation-count-one-to-many/load-relation-count-and-map-one-to-many.ts).

Example code:

```js
this.commentRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('comment')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.commentRatings', 'commentRatings')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.user', 'user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.articles', 'article')
        .loadRelationCountAndMap('user.totalArticle', 'user.articles')
        .where('comment.articleId = :id', { id })
        .select([
          'comment.id',
          'comment.comment',
          'user.name',
          'user.profilePhoto',
          'user.createdOn',
          'commentRatings',
          'comment.createdOn',
        ])
        .orderBy({ 'comment.createdOn': { order: order, nulls: 'NULLS LAST' } })
        .offset(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .getMany()
```

Comment: thanks , but I can't use `user.articles`  since my `queryBuilder` is on `comment` and `entity` will not be recognise in this case. I can use that in subquery though with a different `from`.